# Best way to display different sections in single php page, depending on url passed values

Tags: php, html

I am creating simple CMS which has different sections. They are displayed in a single php file, depending on values which are passed into url. I get those values from url and depending on which value it is I display specific section. I use Switch and Cases to display them.

For example:

There is specific id passed into url and code looks something like this:

```
switch($navSection) {   
                    case "groups": include_once("includes/htmlSectionsForCms/cmsGroups.php"); break;

                    case "teams":
                        subjectHeader("Komandos");
                        break;

                    case "players":
                        subjectHeader("Žaidėjai");
                        break;

                    case "matches":
                        subjectHeader("Varžybos");
                        break;

                    case "matchesStatistics":
                        subjectHeader("Varžybų statistika");
                        break;  

                    case "messages":
                        subjectHeader("Pranešimai");
                        break;

                    case "surveys":
                        subjectHeader("Apklausos");
                        break;

                    default: include_once("includes/htmlSectionsForCms/cmsDefault.php"); break;
                    }
```

Is there a better way to achieve and organize different sections in a single php page using passed variables ?

Comment: "better" is a rather subjective term.  Your method seems fine.  Although if you have any forms where stuff is POST'd you might want to use POST vars for your page sections rather than GET...

Comment: The Stategy design pattern springs to mind.